# REGEX - must contain alphanumeric and slash

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to do a validation that an input field must contain alpha numeric and slash as its value.

Eg: AA/AB/12314/2017/ASD

The above shown is the example of the value that should be the input field.
I don't have any knowledge in writing the regular expressions. So please do help me.

Finally I came up with the below code:

```
var message = $('#message').val();

if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9-/]*$/.test($.trim(message)) == false)
{
    $('#message').focus();
    alert('invalid message');
}
```

Comment: Even if some browsers allow using unescaped `/` inside the character class, it is still a good idea to escape it. What is the problem with your code? Note the `-` before `/` is treated as a literal `-`.

Comment: is your string valid if it contains only alphanumeric characters? Or does it must contain both

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew A `-` is treated as a lteral `-` only if at the very beggining/end of a char class, am I wrong? Which isn't the case here.

Comment: @sp00m most engines also treat it as literal if placed directly after a range, where it thus can't open a range.

Comment: @SebastianProske Just tried, you're right, thanks for the info!

Comment: @Nino : it must contain both alphanumeric and slash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> it must contain both alphanumeric and slash.

I understand that you may have 1+ alphanumeric symbols followed with at least 1 `/` followed with more alphanumeric symbols. You need to change the regex to `/^[a-z\d]+(?:\/[a-z\d]+)+$/i`:

```js
var message = $('#message').val();
if (!/^[a-z\d]+(?:\/[a-z\d]+)+$/i.test($.trim(message)))
{
    $('#message').focus();
    alert('invalid message');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="message" value="ASD/TD"/>
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-z\d]+` - 1 or more letters or digits
- `(?:\/[a-z\d]+)+` - 1 or more sequences of

  - `\/` - slash
  - `[a-z\d]+` - 1 or more letters or digits
- `$` - end of string
- `/i` - a case insensitive modifier, so  that `[a-z]` could also match uppercase ASCII letters.

If you mean there must be a `/` and alphanumeric *anywhere* inside the string, use lookaheads:

```
/^(?=[a-z\d]*\/)(?=\/*[a-z\d])[a-z\d\/]+$/i
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PyfHGw/1). Here, `(?=[a-z\d]*\/)` requires a `/` after 0+ alphanumerics, and `(?=\/*[a-z\d])` requires an alphanumeric after 0+ slashes. `[a-z\d\/]+` will match 1 or more alphanumeric or slashes.

Answer (score 1):

> escaping `/` like `\/`is a good practise but inside of char class, not necessary.
>   the `*` must be changed to `+`. because `*` will also match `null`.
>   also remove the `-` otherwise `-` will also be matched.

```js
function validate(){
  var message = $('#message').val();

  if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9/]+$/.test($.trim(message)) == false){
      $('#message').focus();
     alert('invalid message');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="message"></textarea><button onclick="validate();">Test</button>
```

Comment: `/` doesn't need to be escaped when within a char class.

Comment: @sp00m , I don't know about that exactly.
 but it is a good practise to escape some symbols. also there are some other issues. check the first 3 lines.
anyway, thanks for the information. I will update myself

Comment: Well, I prefer to escape only what effectively needs to be escaped, as regex are sometimes complex enough to understand already, but it's probably a matter of taste :)

Comment: i practised like this till now. Because if I practised otherwise, I sometimes forgot to escape outside a class too. :-)

Comment: so, what are all the symbols needs to be escaped inside a char class?

Comment: I would say only `]` and ``\``.

Comment: usually I escape `/` , _/_ , `$`

Comment: In JS only `]` and \ need to be escaped. `^` and `-` need to be positioned properly to be treated literally. In some engines (e.g. PCRE) even `]` can be positioned as first character to be treated literally, but that's not the case for JS.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkValidity(input){
 var onlyAlphaNum = /^[a-z0-9//]+$/
 return onlyAlphaNum.test(input);
}

var message = $('#message').val();
if(!checkValidity(message)){
 $('#message').focus();
    alert('invalid message');
}
```

> 

Comment: Please let me know why its down voted? so that i can understand my mistake and learn from it

Comment: I am sure the downvote comes from someone who does not know `/[/]/` *may* work in some browsers. Still, it should be escaped to avoid browser compatibility issues.